# Mouse control not responding 

Tags: python, pygame

I've just started using pygame. I've created my game but it's really unstable and crashes (having issues exiting).

I've created a welcome page but it has created a bug with game control (the character controlled by the mouse has stopped responding), I've tried few methods but just results in more game crashes and errors. can you please help me out to debug anything you might spot. you download the game from her http://dl.dropbox.com/u/47312995/Twerk.rar

the code:

```
import pygame
from pygame import *
import random
import time
import os
import sys
from pygame.locals import *


black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)

pygame.init()

def game():

os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED'] = '1'
mouse.set_visible(False)
screen = display.set_mode((800,500))
backdrop = pygame.image.load('bg.jpg').convert_alpha()
menu = pygame.image.load('green.jpg').convert_alpha()
ballpic = pygame.image.load('ball.gif').convert_alpha()
mouseball = pygame.image.load('mouseball.gif').convert_alpha()
display.set_caption('Twerk')
back = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())

def text(text,x_pos,color,font2=28):
    tfont = pygame.font.Font(None, font2)

    text=tfont.render(text, True, color)
    textpos = text.get_rect(centerx=back.get_width()/2)
    textpos.top = x_pos
    screen.blit(text, textpos)

 start = False
 repeat = False
while start == False:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            start = True
            #falling = True
            #finish = True

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                start = True
    #game over screen
    screen.blit(menu,[0,0])
    pygame.display.set_caption("TWERK")

    #Text
    #"Welcome to Escape"
    #needs replacing with logo 
    text("Twerk",60,white,300)

    #"Instructions"
    text("Instructions",310,white)
    text("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------",320,white)
    text("Avoid the the enemies",340,white)
    text("Last as long as you can!",360,white)
    text("Press space to start",420,white)
    pygame.display.flip()


while start == True:
positionx=[]
positiony=[]
positionxmove=[]
positionymove=[]
falling = False
finish = False
score=0
enemies=1
velocity=1

for i in range(enemies):
  positionx.append(random.randint(300,400)+random.randint(-300,200))
  positiony.append(random.randint(200,340)+random.randint(-200,100))
  positionxmove.append(random.randint(1,velocity))
  positionymove.append(random.randint(1,velocity))


font = pygame.font.Font(None, 28)
text = font.render('Starting Twerk... ', True, (100,100,100))
textRect = text.get_rect()
textRect.centerx = screen.get_rect().centerx
textRect.centery = screen.get_rect().centery

screen.blit(backdrop, (0,0))
screen.blit(text, textRect)
pygame.display.update()
game=time.localtime()

while start == True:
  end=time.localtime()
  score= (end[1]-game[1])*3600 + (end[4]-game[4])*60 + end[5]-game[5]
  if score > 1: break

first=True
strtTime=time.localtime()

while not finish or falling:
  screen.blit(backdrop, (0,0))
  for i in range(enemies):
    screen.blit(ballpic,(positionx[i],positiony[i]))
    (mousex,mousey)=mouse.get_pos()
    screen.blit(mouseball,(mousex,mousey))
    display.update()
    strt = time.localtime()

  if first:
    while True:
      end=time.localtime()
      score= (end[3]-strt[3])*3600 + (end[4]-strt[4])*60 + end[5]-strt[5]
      if score > 3: break
    first = False

  if falling:
    for i in range(enemies):
      positionymove[i]=1000
      positionxmove[i]=0


  for i in range(enemies): positionx[i]=positionx[i]+positionxmove[i]
  for i in range(enemies): positiony[i]=min(600,positiony[i]+positionymove[i])

  if falling:
    falling=False
    for posy in positiony:
      if posy<600: falling=True


  if not falling:
    for i in range(enemies):
      for j in range(i+1,enemies):
        if abs(positionx[i]-positionx[j])<20 and abs(positiony[i]-positiony[j])<20:
          temp=positionxmove[i]
          positionxmove[i]=positionxmove[j]
          positionxmove[j]=temp
          temp=positionymove[i]
          positionymove[i]=positionymove[j]
          positionymove[j]=temp

    for i in range(enemies):  
      if positionx[i]>600: positionxmove[i]*=-1
      if positionx[i]<0: positionxmove[i]*=-1
      if positiony[i]>440: positionymove[i]*=-1
      if positiony[i]<0: positionymove[i]*=-1

    for i in range(enemies):
      if abs(positionx[i]-mousex)<40 and abs(positiony[i]-mousey)<40:

        endTime=time.localtime()
        score= (endTime[3]-strtTime[3])*3600 + (endTime[4]-strtTime[4])*60 + endTime[5]-strtTime[5]
        falling = True
        finish = True
game()
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: No one is going to download a `.rar` of your game to help you debug it. Please try to reproduce the problem in as little code as possible, ideally around 10-25 lines of code, and explain what you've done to debug the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Also include the stacktrace of whatever errors you are receiving.

Comment: No problem cheers for pointing out :), @JoelCornett I don't get any errors, only when I try to debug and try new thinks tends to break down even more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're not checking for input.  EACH time through your game loop, you should call pygame.event.get().  For example, from my template code:

```
def quit():
    pygame.quit(); sys.exit()
def GetInput():
    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if   event.type == QUIT: quit()
        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if   event.key == K_ESCAPE: quit()
def Draw():
    pygame.display.flip()
def main():
    Clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    while True:
        GetInput()
        Draw()
        Clock.tick(60)
```